# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID ... failed due to the following error: 80040154

Tags: c#, .net, com

In a C# program (.Net 4.5.2) we are using the following pattern to create instances of COM server classes:

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid, hostname);
server = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Today, for a COM server with a certain guid and `hostname = "localhost"` combination, we ran into the error message you see reproduced in the subject line. Searching the internet we found several hits ("com dll is not registered", "clsid not in registry", replace target "AnyCPU" by "x86" etc), but we could rule out all the explanations we found. For several other servers on the same host our program also worked as expected, while other clients could connect without error to the server.

Fortunately, by accident, a colleague figured out that replacing `"localhost"` for the hostname with a `null` pointer made the program work in our particular example. Unfortunately, I do not understand what's going on here -- could someone with a deeper understanding of the COM model please explain this to me?

According to the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08b442cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid clsid, string server)`, 'If the server name is null, this method automatically reverts to the local machine'. As mentioned earlier, for most servers on the local host, the string "localhost" in this code snippet worked perfectly fine. What could be the reason that in this one case that string has to be replaced by a `null` pointer?

Comment: SO demands that *somebody* is doomed to run into a machine with a mis-configured HOSTS configuration file.  You drew the unlucky lot.  Just use the overload that only takes the Guid, one less failure mode.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your comment. Actually, this happened on at least two different servers in our intranet, which I do think is professionally managed, and in addition it happened (with the same server) on a customer system (where I cannot judge on the quality of the infrastructure). So if this is due do a mis-configured HOSTS configuration would you be so kind to tell me where I can find a more detailed description of what you are referring to? And why does it then affect only one server and not the others? And we do need to cover the case that the server is not 'localhost'.

Comment: (In my comment I wanted to ask: why does it only affect one COM server (on that particular machine) and not the others)